# Get the longest text in HTML document using Jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="customdiv">
<p>AAAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAA</p>
<p>AAAAAA</p>
<p>AAAAAA</p>
</div>
```

I need the output like this:

`Largest value is:AAAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAAA AAAA
Length:37`

Comment: please consider that there may be more than 100 p tag in the html document

Comment: SO start looping.... what did you try?

Comment: You're gonna have to give us a lot more to go on here. Are you *only* looking for `p` tags? Are you only interested in `p` tags that are children of `#customdiv`? What did you try so far? How did that fail?  Etc....

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could attempt to do it:

```
var longest = "";

$('p').each(function() {

  if ($(this).text().length > longest.length) {

    longest = $(this).text();

  }

});

console.log(longest);
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/2yne0qno/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the inner HTML of a tag by using the DOM's innerHTML property.

For your example, you could use

```
function findLongestText() {
  var longestInnerHTML = "";
  var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

  for (var i = 0; i < pTags.length; i++) {
    var innerHTML = pTags[i].innerHTML;

    if (innerHTML.length > longestInnerHTML.length) {
      longestInnerHTML = innerHTML;
    }
  }
  console.log("longest: " + longestInnerHTML);
}
```

to find the longest `p` tag in your document.